# Spring Boot Maven Project : Could not transfer Artifact, Failed to authenticate with proxy

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

Created a sample spring boot project with Eclipse Oxygen. Getting this error when Spring Boot dependency is added.

```
Failed to execute goal on sample-service-1: could not resolve dependencies 
for the project com.xx.sample-service:sample-service-1:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: 
Failed to collect dependencies at org.springframework.boot:spring-boot- 
sample-web:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE -> org.hibernate- 
validator:jar:5.3.6:Final:Failed to read artifact descriptor for 
org.hibernate.validator:hibernatevalidator:jar:5.3.6.Final: Could not 
transfer artifact org.jboss.shrinkwrap:shrinkwrap-bom:pom:1.2.3 from/to 
central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)  Failed to authenticate with 
proxy
```

Please help to find why this error is poping up. Thanks in advance.

Edit - Please find my settings.xml file below. (There may be typos, I've drafted a copy of my settings.xml file manually as I'm working from a copy restricted environment.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd" 
xmlns="maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<localRepository>C:\Users\xxxxxx\Softwares\MavenRepo</localRepository>

<proxies>
    <proxy>
        <active>true</active>
        <protocol>http</protocol>
        <host>intranet-proxy.intranet.xx.com</host>
        <port>8080</port>
        <id>1</id>
    </proxy>
    <proxy>
        <id>2</id>
        <active>true</active>
        <protocol>https</protocol>
        <host>intranet-proxy.intranet.xx.com</host>
        <port>8080</port>
    </proxy>
</proxies>
<servers>
    <server>
        <username>abc@xx.com</username>
        <password>XXXXXX</password>
        <id>central</id>
    </server>
    <server>
        <username>abc@xx.com</username>
        <password>XXXXXX</password>
        <id>snapshots</id>
    </server>
</servers>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
                <id>central</id>
                <name>mvn-libs-release</name>
                <url>https://myurlXXXX</url>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <snapshots/>
                <id>snapshot</id>
                <name>mvn-external-snapshots</name>
                <url>https://myurlXXXX</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
                <id>central</id>
                <name>mvn-plugins-release</name>
                <url>https://myurlXXXX</url>
            </pluginRepository>
            <pluginRepository>
                </snapshots>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <name>mvn-libs-release</name>
                    <url>https://myurlXXXX</url>
            </pluginRepository>
            <pluginRepository>
                <snapshots/>
                <id>snapshots></id>
                <name>mvn-plugins-release</name>
                <url>https://myurlXXXX</url>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>
        <id>artifactory</id>
   </profile>
 </profiles>
   <activeprofiles>
        <activeprofile>artifactory</activeprofile>
   </activeprofiles>
```

Comment: The error is: `Failed to authenticate with proxy` which means you have to use authentication against an proxy...which you haven't configured..

Comment: @khmarbaise I've configured the proxy in .m2/settings.xml file, in which the username and password is correct

Comment: Run `mvn dependency:resolve` from the command line. If it works, need different Eclipse config (maybe it's not using the settings.xml you modified for example). If it doesn't work, the proxy config is likely not correct.

Comment: @AparnaShajiPeter please show your settings.xml file...

Comment: @khmarbaise added the settings.xml file now